# Trouble with form view for multil Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, fields-for

I have Book model and Category Model which have many-many relationship and Book_Category model include their id. 
I use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_categories` for create new book then update Book_Category table. 
My params is `params.require(:book).permit(:name, :description, :author, book_categories_attributes:[])`
. I just test in rails c first and it work. `Book.create!(name: 'asdsadsa',description: 'asdasdasdsadasdsadsad',author: 'asdsadasdasd',book_categories_attributes: [{ category_id: 1},{ category_id: 2}])` but i dont know how to create view to send array hash category to controller.

Comment: You can use cocoon gem. It has some good examples in the readme file.

Answer (score 0):

Rails have a great gem to deal with nested attributes https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Also, Ryan Bates (gem author) made an example app https://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples/tree/nested_form

And at last here is a relevant RailsCast episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1